# How to add a face outside a round feature

Tags: faces

How can I fill in a face and still keep the circle/cylinder open[image: cylinder where the end needs to be open]

If I choose make face here the opening in the cylinder also gets covered.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89974/retopologizing-circular-window or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/topology-question-regarding-circular-holes

Comment: Duarte, thanks for your suggestions, but neither seems to deal with adding a face.  I want to fill in the space around the circle without filling it it.  This is all one object so Knife Project cannot be used here as that requires two objects.  And the other links seems to deal with changing the topology of a flat surface, which is not what I'm working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding an answer so it can be marked as solved :).

- You can use Bridge Edge Loops for that.
- While in *Edit Mode* select both Loops and go *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*
- Note that it will create triangles. To make quads, you also need to subdivide the rectangle.

[image]